# jQuery - How to find out when a checkbox gets changed programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Consider the following HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked />
```

A bit later the checkbox get's unchecked:

```
$('#checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

How can I find out (with jQuery) when the `checked` attribute  changes? The `.change()` event handler doesn't trigger when I check / uncheck the checkbox programmatically like above.

Comment: Fyi, with recent jQuery versions you should use `.prop('checked', false)` to uncheck it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOM events do not fire when triggered programmatically (spelling?). However the events attached via jQuery do if you trigger them via jQuery `trigger`.

[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/JUKSA/)

Answer (score 2):

As what liho1eye said. You can use the jquery trigger function for this.

Check this [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/psGD8/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked />
```

jQuery:

```
// Remove the first checked attr
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', false);

// Bind checkbox to click
$('#checkbox').bind('click', function() { // jQuery 1.7 you can use .on()
   alert('You clicked the checkbox! Naughty boy!');
});

// execute the event for the matched elements.
$('#checkbox').trigger('click');
```